# How to get the stretched height of JasperReport's 5.9.0 TextField with help of JasperReports API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, textfield

I encountered a problem, how to calculate the required height of the text in the TextField with "Stretch with Overflow" attribute in Java.

I have been trying for a whole day, but I still don't have a better idea. I have two ideas.

1. The first is to put the text in the TextFiled and get the height, but the obtained height is always the original height of the TextField.
2. The second is to put the TextField into JRDesignBand and get the next Band Y-axis height, but I don't know how to achieve it.

I need to calculate the height accurately to achieve a strict report format, so I really need to use this method. Thank you very much for your help.

The following snippet code I tried.

```
JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
textField.setWidth(183);
textField.setHeight(38);
textField.setStyle(normalStyle);
textField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
textField.setExpression(expression);
System.err.println("TextField Height: " + textField.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the method I chose is 1.
Finally, I thought that the time to change the height of the TextField is when filling in the data, so I should try the JasperPrint obtained after the execution of JasperFillManager.fillReport to get the height of the component.

The following is part of the code I executed.

```
   JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
   textField.setWidth(183);
   textField.setHeight(38);
   textField.setStyle(normalStyle);
   textField.setStretchWithOverflow(true);
   JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
   expression.setText("$P{MyText}");
   textField.setExpression(expression);

   //Omitted

   JRDesignBand band = new JRDesignBand();
   band.addElement(textField);
   ((JRDesignSection) jasperDesign.getDetailSection()).addBand(band);
   
   //Omitted

   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   params.put("MyText", myText);
   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,  new 
   JREmptyDataSource());
   List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
   int height = pages.get(0).getElements().get(0).getHeight();
```